# stop google chrome "translate this page" using php

Tags: php

I've been developing a quiz application. I'm facing a problem. When student giving test for Finish to English word meaning, they can easily get the English word using google translate. Is there any solution in PHP so that I can stop language translation of google crhome browser?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use html lang attribute

`<html xml:lang="en" lang="en"></html>`

and add before `</head>`

`<meta name="google" content="notranslate"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, its not working

Comment: Your meta tag was not displaying because of your formatting. This is fixed now. @BiplobSarkar you should try this again.